# Using Functor to make a custom sort method in sets

Tags: c++, sorting, set

I am trying to make a custom sorting method for `set` but the compiler doesn't run it.
For example we are inserting the following numbers: 2 3 5 4 , `set` will sort them from the lowest value to the highest value, but what if I want it from the highest to the lowest?
For : 2 3 5 4, instead of sorting them like this 2 3 4 5, I want 5 4 3 2.
I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct SortOrder {
    bool operator()(const int &first,const int &last) {
        if (first < last);
            return (first < last);
        return (first > last);
    }
};

int main(){
    set<int,SortOrder> date;
    set<int>::iterator it;
    date.insert(2);
    date.insert(3);
    date.insert(5);
    date.insert(4);
    for (it = date.begin(); it != date.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it <<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of comparator is incorrect, as deepmax has explained: your operator returns `false` only when the two items are equal to each other; in all other cases it returns `true`, effectively making it a "not equal" operator.

You don't have to write your own implementation, because C++ Standard Library provides an implementation for you:

```
set<int,std::greater<int>> date;
```

[`std::greater<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) is the comparator that you want ([demo](http://ideone.com/UtiePU)).

```
set<int,std::greater<int>> date {2, 3, 5, 4};
ostream_iterator<int> out_it (cout, " ");
copy (date.begin(), date.end(), out_it );
```